# error connecting to database with mysqldriver

Tags: mysql, go

I'm trying to follow the instructions here https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#installation and http://go-database-sql.org/accessing.html to create a sql.db.

The first line of my code has this

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "username@localhost/my_db")
```

When I ran the program on the terminal, I got this:

```
Default addr for network ''localhost'' unknown
```

Why is this? When I checked the user and host to mysql it states 'username' and 'localhost'. I followed the parameters like this:

```
[username[:password]@][protocol[(address)]]/dbname[?param1=value1&...&paramN=valueN]
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You might want to specify the protocol (like '`tcp`'), instead of `localhost` directly.
See [those examples](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#examples):

```
user:password@tcp(localhost:5555)/dbname
```

In your case:

```
username@tcp(localhost)/my_db
```

---

Note, if you use the default protocol (`tcp`) and host (`localhost:3306`), this could be rewritten as

```
user:password@/dbname
```

---

[Lakshminarayanan Guptha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426121/lakshminarayanan-guptha) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244089/error-connecting-to-database-with-mysqldriver/25244131#comment132312775_25244131):

> In my case `- user:password@tcp/dbname` worked

Comment: Ok a very basic question: I changed it to username@tcp(localhost)/my_db and got this error - dial tcp: missing port in address localhost. What is this port number?

Comment: I added :5555 and tcp to localhost and got this: connection refused

Comment: @user3918985 the port on which your mysql is running (default 3306)

Comment: ok user@/dbname worked. thanks. not sure why the localhost param didn't work though.

Comment: You saved my night ;) Cheers!

Comment: I was also facing this issue in localhost and user:password@/dbname worked for me :-)

Comment: in my case - `user:password@tcp/dbname` this worked

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the most voted answer couldn't help me. What saved me was putting `(host:port)` inside quotation --> `"(host:port)"`

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue as I was running Docker containers on my Linux VM. In my application (`server.go`) I changed the localhost value to use the IP of my virtual machine and then build and ran the container successfully.

```
mysql container (3307) <--> [(application mysql:<vm ip>:3307) container](expose 3000) <-->  world
```